# Problem with 'insert_at_cursor' attribute

Tags: application-development, python, gtk, quickly

I made something, so after clicking a button, some text should appear in the `TextView`. Part of my code:

```
def on_button1_clicked(self, builer):
        self.writetest = self.builder.get_object("textview1")
        self.writetest.insert_at_cursor("something")
```

Unfortunately, when I click the button I get:

```
AttributeError: 'TextView' object has no attribute 'insert_at_cursor'
```

According to GTK Documentation there is such attribute: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html#GtkTextView-insert-at-cursor

I have the same problem with `Entry` as well, if I change `TextView` to `Entry`.
But if I use `set_text` instead of `insert_at_cursor` in my code, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are looking for is not on TextView, but on TextBuffer. So you need to do:

```
buffer = self.writetest.get_buffer()
buffer.insert_at_cursor('Hello World!')
```

The documentation link you gave does not point to a method, but rather to a signal. Signals cannot be directly called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought signals could be used as methods.